# How to start a file that has a period in front of it?

Tags: python, file, batch-file, python-3.x

Im using os.startfile to start a bat but i can't find a way to start a bat file that has a period infront of its name.

example of what i want to achieve:

```
import os
import subprocess
os.startfile('C:\\folder\\proov\\.batch.bat')
```

Comment: What is the error thrown? Any stacktrace would help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use raw strings:

```
import os
os.startfile(r'C:\folder\proov\.batch.bat')
```

Note that for a batch file, you can simply do:

```
import os
os.system(r'C:\folder\proov\.batch.bat')
```

Or

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(r'C:\folder\proov\.batch.bat')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.startfile(os.path.join("c:\\folder\\proov\\", ".batch.bat"))
```